# Thieves for questioning

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

The police got three thieves when they tried to rob a bank. But the officer wants to give them a chance to get free, so he asks them who is the main brain behind the robbery. The thieves were puzzle lovers and that's why they did not answer directly. Instead, they said which of them is lying.

- Rob says that John is always lying
- John says that Patrick is always lying
- Patrick says that both Rob and John are always lying

The question is:

Which people are lying? We accept that each of the three either always lies or always tells the truth.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you write this puzzle yourself, or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: Together with some of my friends, we are trying to create a good logic puzzle. You successfully found true tellers, but you are right that the logic behind the puzzle does not reveal who might be the master mind behind the robbery plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Patrick is telling the truth, then Rob and John are both lying, but Rob's statement is true. Contradiction, so Patrick is lying. That means John is telling the truth, which means Rob is lying.

So the only truth-teller is John. I still don't know who was the mastermind behind the bank robbery though ...